# jQuery load() not working as expected on textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to get user content from PHP file with `load()` function and show it in the textarea which works fine however same process won't work if the user type something in the texarea beforehand. Anyone has a solution to it?

*For example:* Type something in textarea and click links which won't change the content of texarea.

Thanks in advance

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function show_content(display_field, id)
{
    $('#' + display_field).load('data.php?id=' + id);
}
</script>


<a href="#nogo" onClick="show_content('content_area', '1')" title="View">User 1</a>
<a href="#nogo" onClick="show_content('content_area', '2')" title="View">User 2</a>
<a href="#nogo" onClick="show_content('content_area', '3')" title="View">User 3</a>

<textarea id="content_area" rows="10" cols="10"></textarea>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$content[1] = 'This belongs to User 1';
$content[2] = 'This belongs to User 2';
$content[3] = 'This belongs to User 3';

echo $content[$_GET['id']];
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `load()` sets the `html` rather than the `value`.

You could use this:

```
function show_content(display_field, id) {
    $.get( 'data.php?id=' + id, function( data ) {
        $('#' + display_field).val(data);
    });
}
```

**[.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)**

Answer (score 0):

You did not state what "won't work" means.  If you mean the textarea contents sometimes appears incorrectly, I suspect it is because you are launching three asynchronous calls to $(#xxx).load(();  Each will execute independently and in the future update your textarea in a random order.

Instead do something like this:

```
 $('#temp').load('data.php?id=' + id, function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
     $('#display_field).val($('#temp').val());
);
```

Each result will execute serially, loading in your results.  They may not be in the order you called them though.